# Ubuntu 12.10 64bit is not shown on win7 pc in boot menu.

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-7

I have tried EasyBCD but it didn't worked for me. I am trying for a dual boot menu. I am installing with a bootable usb

Comment: Why not don't you use Grub? Can you explain why you want to use EasyBCD?

Comment: If you're setting up the boot menu with EasyBCD, then the problem probably is a misconfiguration in that program, and I don't think we can help you with that here, EasyBCD being a Windows program AFAICT. If all you want is to dual boot and it doesn't _have_ to be with EasyBCD, then you can use Grub _instead_, as @ToDo suggested. Just install Ubuntu after Windows and let it create its own boot menu; it will automatically add an entry for Windows.

Comment: Do you reinstall Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Ubuntus own bootloader: grub/grub2? They are far more convenient to use with multiple systems. Instructions on how to install one of these on a running system you may find here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System